# Passing a URL as text through the WhatsApp URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, url-scheme

I am trying to pass a Google Maps URL as the text through the Whatsapp URL scheme.

I am trying to encode it but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
let message = "View my current location at http://maps.google.com/?q=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"

var completewhatsappURLString = whatsappURL + message

completewhatsappURLString = completewhatsappURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let completeURL = NSURL(string: completewhatsappURLString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mapsURL = "comgooglemaps://?q=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
let message = "View my current location at \(mapsURL)" as CFString
let encodedString: String = String(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, message, nil, "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]" as CFString, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue))
let completewhatsappURLString = "whatsapp://send?text=" + encodedString
let completeURL = NSURL(string: completewhatsappURLString)
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(completeURL!)) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(completeURL!)
}
```